# Reformat the 'Created' SharePoint column to something readable in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, date, format, whencreated

I have a flow that sends an email to an item's original submitter.  In this email I need to display the Item's Created Date AND Time.  I'm looking to display something like "11/14/2023 2:40pm".  None of the formatting I've tried in the flow seem to work.  Could someone please help me format this?  I'm assuming I need to either use the Compose action, or set a variable.  I haven't been able to get this right yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/how-to-customize-or-format-date-and-time-values-in-flow), you can use `formatDateTime`.

For example, to inject the `Created` date of a new SharePoint item in a variable of type `string`:

```
formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/Created'], 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt')
```

or, with the `g` format:

```
formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/Created'], 'g')
```

[image: formatDateTime definition]
[image: formatDateTime result]

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  I used the first method you listed.